# Domain Data Source CanLoad is false when using RIA Query Parameter bound to a dependency property

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, ria, domaindatasource

I have a ria DDS query whose parameter is bound to a dependency property of the code behind my silverlight page. The issue is that once the project dependency is changed I get the following error.

QueryParameters cannot be changed when CanLoad is false.  Changing the QueryParameters initiates a load operation, and load operations are not permitted when CanLoad is false.  Controls that invoke load operations should be disabled when CanLoad is false.

I'm at a loss on how to complete or cancel the load so I can change the details view for a project every time a new project is selected from a list.

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my1:XT_PROJECTS, CreateList=true}" Height="0" LoadedData="ProjectDetailsDomainDataSource_LoadedData" Name="ProjectDetailsDomainDataSource" QueryName="getProjectDetails"  Width="0" >
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:MYservices />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="project" Value="{Binding ElementName=ProjectDetailsPage, Path=project}" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

public static readonly DependencyProperty projectIDDP =
    DependencyProperty.Register("project", typeof(string),typeof(ProjectDetails),
    new PropertyMetadata(""));
 public string projectID
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(projectIDDP);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(projectIDDP, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem doesn't occur for me in most simple scenarios. A load triggered by a change in a bound parameter value doesn't make CanLoad become false. Fast subsequent changes to the parameter don't cause the error you're describing (in fact the the scenario is handled quite gracefully). Although I have seen the error message myself (also with load-only activity), I have not been able to produce a simple test case that shows it.

My suspicion is that I always used shared contexts in those cases. If you have a test case isolating the problem, I'd appreciate it if you share it.

Comment: This is such an old issue I had and I'm not longer working with this technology stack so I can't really vote for or against the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research I'm now pretty sure you must have pending changes in you context. In that case, DomainDataSources "block" and you must not cause a load for them.

If this error occurs in a different scenario, I'd be very interested to be corrected on this.

If you have pending changes, your solution is either

1. to block user input (presumably the ultimate cause of your load), for example by disabling the form or
2. to use a different context for the submission and the DomainDataSource (you will then want to use RiaServicesContrib to do copying of entities between contexts).

Comment: i got this when adding a 'new' child entity to something that would optionally have been saved later. I had to change to not attaching it until I was actually saving it. Not really happy with this but it's just one small feature to add to an ancient project so I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work adding a submit before changing the parameter? 
like this

```
set
{ 
    if (xyzDomainDataSource.HasChanges)
        xyzDomainDataSource.SubmitChanges();
    SetValue(projectIDDP, value);        
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing too, but I would prefer to know what's really going on here. Doesn't seem like this should be nessecary...

Comment: That won't work either. You have to wait until the submission is complete before you can change the dependency.